# How do I split latitude and longitude into separate strings?

Tags: java, android

I have getting current location(longitudes and latitudes) using this code:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
Log.d("My_Loc",latLng.toString());
```

And the result is:
`Output: My_Loc: lat/lng: (12.9153443,80.146238)`

I want to split this output and store like:

```
longi=12.9153443

lati=80.1446238
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the "(" and ")" included within the string all the time?

Comment: Just use split(",") and then you will get array of two strings then store them as you like

Comment: Why don't you just use 
`Log.d("long", "="+location.getLongitude()); 
Log.d("lati", "="+location.getLatitude());`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam : Yes your solution is right. You have solved my other errors as well. Thanks for your help (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the [**`LatLng`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) class of the Google API,  you could use the [**`latitude`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#latitude) & [**`longitude`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#longitude) public fields.

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
double longitude = latLng.longitude;
double latitude = latLng.latitude;
```

Alternatively,
if the data will be retrieved in this format all the time:

> (12.9153443,80.146238)

then you can use this solution:

```
String data = "(12.9153443,80.146238)"; // assume this is the data
String [] tempArray = data.substring(data.indexOf("(")+1, data.lastIndexOf(")")).split(",");
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[1]);
```

though I'd suggest to go with the first solution.